# c++ return value in if statement

Tags: c++

This is a really simple question.

Say I have a function :

```
 int fun(int n){
     if (n > 3)
         return n;
     else
         fail(); // this function outputs error message 
                 // and terminates the program
                 // no return value
 }
```

Then there is no return value for cases where n <=3. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Depending on the context throwing except would make sense.

Comment: What about it needs fixing?  Do you want to avoid a warning?

Comment: when the program is terminating in `fail()`, what will you do with the return value?

Comment: Instead of calling the `fail`-method, you can throw an `std::invalid_argument`-exception. Then, you can do the error handling outside.

Comment: Given what the function actually does, `#define ASSERT(x) if(!x) fail();` would do fine. `ASSERT(x<3); ContinueMyExecution();` - for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int fun (int n)
{
    if (n <= 3) { fail(); /* Does not return. */ }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're just trying to squelch a warning about "control reaches end of non-void function" or something along those lines, you can decorate `fail()` with some compiler-specific directives that indicate it doesn't return.  In GCC & Clang, that would be `__attribute__((noreturn))`, for example.

Example:

```
$ cat example.cpp 
void fail(void);

int fun(int n)
{
  if (n > 3)
    return n;
  else
    fail();
}
$ clang++ -c example.cpp 
example.cpp:9:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function
      [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
$ cat example2.cpp 
void fail(void) __attribute__((noreturn));

int fun(int n)
{
  if (n > 3)
    return n;
  else
    fail();
}
$ clang++ -c example2.cpp
$
```

Comment: If you can move over to the dark side and become a C programmer, you may also be able to use the new `_Noreturn` function specifier in C11.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths C++11 has `[[noreturn]]`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Even better!

Answer (score 1):

One possible idiom is to define `fail` as returning an int and then write:

```
int fun(int n){
    if (n > 3)
        return n;
    else
        return fail();                            

}
```

Comment: A workaround maybe, but "idiom" implies something that can be used in different contexts, and you would need one `fail` function for each fake return type.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I chose "idiom" because, even if in this specific case it is a workaround, it is a technique you can use also in other contexts. The "idiom" here is "returning the (fake) value from a function that doesn't actually return".

Comment: That "idiom" is quite misleading.

Comment: @PeteBecker Mmmh, upon further reflection probably you are right in the context of C++ and exceptions. I've programmed more in C lately, this may have biased my perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare an error code that will indicate that something is wrong with the function.

For example:

```
const int error_code = -1;

int fun (int n) {

    if (n > 3) 
        return n;

    fail();
    return error_code;

}
```

Comment: Defining behavior that never happens is a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

Another neat way is to use [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/examples.html#boost_optional.examples.optional_return_values) as the return value. This would indicate the return value many not be set in failure cases and this can be further checked by caller to take subsequent action.

Answer (score -1):

Building on Aesthete's answer:

```
int fun (int n)
{
    if (n <= 3) { fail(); return -1; } //-1 to indicate failure
    return n;
}
```

Comment: What if `-1` is a valid return?

Comment: -1 can be replaced by whatever the user wants to use to indicate failure. I just put it there as a placement for whatevery value they want

Comment: `-1` *isn't* a valid return value in OP's exact case, but your function still has different semantics, technically.  OP appears to be asking about how to avoid this kind of workaround.

Comment: What if _any int_ is a valid return?

Comment: We don't know what's valid or what's not, but it gives the appearance of wrong meaning and misleadingly defines behavior for a case that never happens. Terrible.